# why is this PDO insert not working?

Tags: php, pdo

please help , this is not inserting into db

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog', root, root);

if($dbh){

// use the connection here

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (blog_id,dateposted,name,comment) VALUES (:blog_id,:dateposted,:name,:comment)");
$stmt->bindParam(':blog_id', $validentry);
$stmt->bindParam(':dateposted', NOW());
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name']);
$stmt->bindParam(':comment', $_POST['comment']);
$stmt->execute();

// and now we're done; close it

}else{
    echo mysql_error();
}

$dbh = null;
//redirect after posting
```

Comment: what's with errors? If there are no errors - then either you don't see them or there are no errors and code just works fine.

Comment: no error page just go blank after posting

Comment: turn on errors. It was discussed million times here. Search for error_reporting() + display_errors. Also read how to retrieve errors from PDO. `mysql_error` has nothing to do with PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `NOW()` to `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Comment: depending on actual time setup and timezones this can cause some issues. I'd suggest just to replace placeholder with `NOW()` directly in query.

Comment: That should not work at all using `PDOStatement::bindParam()`

Answer (score 3):

> $stmt->bindParam(':dateposted', NOW());

[`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) binds the parameter to a PHP variable reference. As such, it requires the second argument to be a variable.

You can instead use [`PDOStatement::bindValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) to use a literal or return value from a function.

Also, `NOW()` is not a PHP function and as such, cannot be used here. If you're just wanting to use the DB function, hard-code it into the statement, eg

```
INSERT INTO comments (blog_id,dateposted,name,comment)
VALUES (:blog_id, NOW(), :name, :comment)
```

Answer (score 0):

Phil, ok, but if you need the bindParam to assign a value depending a condition?

In my case, I want to let the user define the creation date if he wants to.

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO news (title_fr, content_fr, creation_date) VALUES (:title_fr, :content_fr, :creation_date)');

if( $date ) {
    $stmt->bindParam(':creation_date', $date);
} else {
    $stmt->bindParam(':creation_date', NOW());
}
```